# 3 java daemon threads are looping on . If threads loop infinitely, CPU consumption will start to spike up

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-dump

On analysing my thread dumps using an online tool fastthread.io, I am getting an error-"3 java daemon threads are looping on".
The stacktrace of the looping threads are:

```
Signal Dispatcher
threadId:4 - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
prio=9 blockedtime=0 blockedcount=0 waitedtime=0 waitedcount=0

Attach Listener
threadId:5 - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
prio=5 blockedtime=0 blockedcount=0 waitedtime=0 waitedcount=0

DestroyJavaVM
threadId:188 - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
prio=5 blockedtime=0 blockedcount=0 waitedtime=0 waitedcount=0
```

I am currently on java 11.0.9.
I am facing cpu spikes in my windows server.

Comment: So what is the question? I don't see any question mark.

Comment: Why these threads are looping ?

Comment: I am quite sure they are not looping. The error message is misleading. `Signal Dispatcher` and `Attach Listener` threads are always shown as `RUNNABLE` when idle, and this is normal. So, the question should be "Why fastthread.io tells such weird things?" instead. And the answer is "because the tool is wrong".